# How can I remove corpses?

Tags: xcom-2

One of my biggest problems with XCOM 2, specifically the Avenger Defense mission, is the enemy corpses.  When you save a game, and reload it, it saves the position of all the corpses, so corpses don't disappear at all. If you're like me, and you use the Avenger Defense mission as a way to fully promote your squad, once you get to 50 enemies killed it starts lagging hard, due to the amount of corpses on screen.

What setting do I need to tweak in the .ini files to remove corpses? This is getting fairly annoying as I have had to force evac when my team was healthy enough to continue the fight, but my computer couldn't stand it anymore.

Comment: There might be a console command for it if the ini files don't have an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible in the base game. The position of the corpses are saved because it is possible for corpses to be interacted with (i.e. Zombified).

I'd imagine the corpses are not removed (unlike debris and building destructions, which *are*) for this reason.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a console command for this for a mod.
I don't have time to publish a mod at the moment but you can easily copy this function into your own mod
that you can create with `XCOM 2 Development Tools` from Steam.

Guide to create mods is here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/xcom2mods/comments/5oz2n5/how_to_compile_metamods_with_long_war_2/

You also need to enable the Console.

This function should keep all the corpses for looting if looting is possible.

```
exec function RemoveCorpses() {
    
    local XComGameStateHistory History;
    local XComGameState NewGameState;
    
    local XComGameState_Unit UnitState;
 
    History = `XCOMHISTORY;
    
    NewGameState = class'XComGameStateContext_ChangeContainer'.static.CreateChangeState("Cleanup corpses");
    
    foreach History.IterateByClassType(class'XComGameState_Unit', UnitState) {
        
        // IsSoldier()
        // XComHQ.IsUnitInSquad(UnitState.GetReference())
        if( UnitState.IsPlayerControlled() || UnitState.bSpawnedFromAvenger ) {
            
        } else {
            if (UnitState.IsDead()) {
                UnitState = XComGameState_Unit(NewGameState.CreateStateObject(class'XComGameState_Unit', UnitState.ObjectID));
                
                class'Helpers'.static.OutputMsg("Removing Corpse of " $ UnitState.GetFullName() $ " " $
                        UnitState.GetMyTemplateName());
                
                UnitState.RemoveUnitFromPlay();   
                NewGameState.AddStateObject(UnitState);                
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    `XCOMGAME.GameRuleset.SubmitGameState(NewGameState);
}
```